# read random objects from Vector java

Tags: java, vector

Hi I'm writing a java program in which I need to read the objects added to a Vector random and there should not be repetition. actually I wanted to have a random number by Math.random() * Vector.size() and not to have repetition, keep the random number in an array or something not to read it again next time but guess there must be a method or something for this purpose ... 
I'll be thankful for any responce

Comment: Please post what you have tried. We're not in the habit of just writing your code for you.

Comment: Also `Vector` is an outdated collection in Java nowadays and you should not be using it unless you have to. `ArrayList` is preferable.

Comment: I don't want you to send me a code but wanted to know if there is a Class or some method to read random elements from vector without repetition

Comment: Collections.shuffle(List)

Answer (score 2):

You could generate a sequence from `1` until the size of the vector, shuffle it, then read elements from the vector using those values:

```
Vector v;
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    values.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(values);

// now read the value in the vector using this random sequence
for (int i=0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
    System.out.println(vector.get(values.get(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remove a value from your vector when it was read.

Comment: yeah but I need the elements after the procedure :)   :(

Comment: Use a copy of your vector :)

Comment: Umm should it be done by vector2 = (Vector) vector 1.clone() ?

Comment: Yes, you can make a copy by `clone()`, or you can make a copy by yourself.
But as @Michael said above, `Vector` is an outdated collection, you better should try to use `ArrayList` for example.